# Can Strongloop generate string uids?

Tags: api, model, uniqueidentifier, strongloop, uid

I want to stop using autogenerated number ids for my models on Strongloop. Can Strongloop generate string uids like e.g. `067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, strong-loop will generate uuid with uuid function call in model definition. you can use something like below in your model properties.

```
"id": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultFn": "uuid"
}
```

You can check below url to get more info.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html and https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/292.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the .js file along with the .json file.
Based on the logic, you can also add a remote method and generate the uuid from node-uuid module.

I'm assuming a User model here and properties of id, name, age and creating an entry into User model.

User.json

```
{
    "name": "User",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "id": true,
          "defaultFn": "uuid",
          "required": true
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        }
}
```

User.js

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
module.exports = function(User) {        
    var userObj = {};
    userObj.id = uuid();
    userObj.name = 'John';
    userObj.age = 22;
    User.create(userObj, function(err, userInstance){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (userInstance) {
            console.log(userInstance);
        }
    });
}
```

This will work.

Comment: "You also need to modify the .js file along with the .json file." What does that "also" refer to? [Saikumar Anireddy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41240905/3982001)? If so, please [edit] your question and make it explicit. Thank you!

Comment: I was refering to the earlier answer. In ny experience I needed to make changes in both files for the id to be autogenerated automatically.